# Java based Atom/RSS Library that works in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rss, atom-feed

I am trying to publish an Atom/RSS feed in my Java based Google App Engine code. I have tried using Rome and keep getting the following error (tried googling without success), also the code I am running that generates the error is the demo code (so I get the feeling Rome won't work with GAE)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/JDOMException
    at com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedOutput.<init>(SyndFeedOutput.java:44)
```

What I am looking for is recommendations for a simple Java library to create and publish an Atom feed from within Google App Engine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/JDOMException
> ```

This just means that the particular class is missing in the runtime classpath (while it was available in the compiletime classpath, that's the difference with ClassNotFoundException).

Logical next step would be to include the particular class (or more actually, the JAR file with the particular class) in the runtime classpath. Then this error wil gone.

Check your compiletime classpath if it is there and add it to runtime classpath. Or if it is actually a dependency which you don't have yet, then it's good to know that the package name already hints that you could find and download it at http://jdom.org.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Giving that a try now. I'm not a new programmer, but I am new to java.

Answer (score 2):

@Adriana and any other people late to the thread:
What Balus meant was that  the original poster, was missing the JDOM library, which can be downloaded at http://jdom.org/. You just need to add the .jar to the classpath, which the ROME demo code apparently was lacking.